# why width of container is zero in react testing with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am new at jest.
I was trying to get width of container but width of container is 0.
Why?
Here is code.

```
test('test Currency List Table', () => {
  const {container } = render(<CurrencyList />);
  console.log('width', container.scrollWidth, container.clientWidth, container.offsetWidth );
  // All of these are zero
  expect(container.clientWidth).toEqual(600);
});
```

CurrencyList is Mui Table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `jsdom` doesn't support **Layout**. See [Unimplemented parts of the web platform](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#unimplemented-parts-of-the-web-platform)

> **Layout**: the ability to calculate where elements will be visually laid out as a result of CSS, which impacts methods like `getBoundingClientRects()` or properties like `offsetTop`.

You have to mock these properties of an HTML element.

> using `Object.defineProperty()` to change what various layout-related getters and methods return.